# How to make JWT Token Authentication on pure Django without React?

Tags: javascript, django, authentication, jwt

I am backend dev, and I want to make website without front end, like react or other front end libraries, just on pure Django. I made on Django a website, all is done, and now it is time for JWT Token Authentication.

Is it possible to make it on pure Django, if yes can you give me a hint how, the best will be some videos or done projects. Thanks in advice :))

Answer (score 1):

If the whole site is Django based, including the rendered HTML - then the best way to go should be using Django's built in authentication system.

[Django Authentication](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/auth/default/#auth-web-requests)